# Remove whitespace and newlines - beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Using Beautifulsoup, I am scraping the following web source:

```
<div>
<p class="introduction">    Manchester City&#039;s Fabian Delph limped off in     the first minute of England Euro 2016 qualifier against Switzerland with a suspected hamstring injury. </p>
<p>    The 25-year-old midfielder, who signed for City from Aston Villa in the summer, pulled up suddenly during Tuesday&#039;s game at Wembley. </p>
<p>    Delph was picked in Roy Hodgson&#039;s first XI having been left out of the starting line-up against San Marino on Saturday.</p>
<p>    Delph was making his eighth appearance for England.</p>
</div>
```

I use the following codes:

```
for item in soup.find_all('div'):
    print item.find('p').text.replace('\n','')
```

This works, but the outcome looks like this (more like four separate values):

```
Manchester City's Fabian Delph limped off in the first minute of England's Euro 2016 qualifier against Switzerland with a suspected hamstring injury.

The 25-year-old midfielder, who signed for City from Aston Villa in the summer, pulled up suddenly during Tuesday's game at Wembley.

Delph was picked in Roy Hodgson's first XI having been left out of the starting line-up against San Marino on Saturday.

Delph was making his eighth appearance for England.
```

How can I get the output in the following format (more like a single value):

```
Manchester City's Fabian Delph limped off in the first minute of England's Euro 2016 qualifier against Switzerland with a suspected hamstring injury. The 25-year-old midfielder, who signed for City from Aston Villa in the summer, pulled up suddenly during Tuesday's game at Wembley. Delph was picked in Roy Hodgson's first XI having been left out of the starting line-up against San Marino on Saturday. Delph was making his eighth appearance for England.
```

Ultimately, I want to save this data in a csv file. The above content should be considered a single value (not four values) in the csv file.

Comment: You are calling the print statement four times, so it's returning it as four values.

Comment: You're correct. I think I need to revise my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
divs = soup.find_all('div')
result = ''.join([div.find('p').text.replace('\n','') for div in divs])
print result
```

The second line gets all of the div paragraph texts on a list and joins them one after another. You can check the [str.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) function.

This approach is faster than summing all of the strings (which is also a valid, correct and good enough), because it does not create extra strings on the process.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is calling print function. print just prints the string to console then prints newline character. You can have a one big string like below

```
big_string = ""
for item in soup.find_all('div'):
  big_string += item.find('p').text.replace('\n','')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the print statement four times, so it's displaying on four lines.

Try this modification

```
single_string_answer = ''
for item in soup.find_all('div'): 
    item.find('p').text.replace('\n','')
    single_string_answer += str(item)
print single_string_answer
```

Comment: Tim, those brackets were intended to make the syntax uniform across both python 2 and 3.